# How to verify a mathematical expression?

Tags: c, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm writing a scientific calculator, and am currently on the stage of tokenising the infix string. I've also implemented a working Dijkstra's Method (I think this is also known as the Shunting-Yard algorithm). However currently, I have no means of validating the input string, which of course is an issue I'll need to resolve before I start evaluating the expression.

As I see it, I currently have three options as to at what stage I should validate the expression:

- Validate the infix string while I'm tokenising it;
- Validate the infix token list during its conversion to Reverse Polish notation (using Dijkstra's Method/S.Y. Algorithm);
- Validate the Reverse Polish token list after it has been converted (I believe that Dijkstra's method catches some errors anyway).

In theory, I could also validate the raw input string before I even tokenise it, but this seems stupid, but I'm not ruling it out if it would be better.

I have researched in a few places, and have gathered a rough idea, but nothing that I can currently convert into an implementation (apologies for inconsistent formatting, I'm 15 and have therefore have a few more years before I get to experience the beautiful world of citation formatting):

- 'Computer Science' by C.S. French (June 1980), ISBN-13: [9780905435138](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780905435138). Pages 228 through 232 describe Dijkstra's Method;
- Brown, B., (2001). Postfix Notation Mini-Lecture. Retrieved on 2018/3/26 from: http://bbrown.spsu.edu/web_lectures/postfix/;
- The Reverse Polish Notation on Wikipedia. Retrieved on 2018/3/26 from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

---

So my current situation is that I have string that can be tokenised, and then converted to Reverse Polish notation. At what point in the aformentioned process(es) should I validate the input string, and how can I go about that?

Thanks.

BTW; incase it is relevant, I tokenise the string into a list of the following structure, `token_t`.

```
typedef long double num_t;

typedef enum {
    EXP = 0,
    DIV = 1,
    MUL = 2,
    ADD = 3,
    SUB = 4,
    U_MIN = 5 // unary minus
} operator_t;

typedef enum {
    ROOT = 0,
    ABS = 1,
    SIN = 2,
    COS = 3,
    TAN = 4,
    SEC = 5,
    CSC = 6,
    LOG = 7
} function_t;

typedef enum {
    BRACKET_OPEN = 0,
    BRACKET_CLOSE = 1
} bracket_t;

typedef enum {
    OPERATOR = 0,
    FUNCTION = 1,
    BRACKET = 2,
    NUMBER = 3
} token_type_t;

typedef struct {
    token_type_t type;

    union {
        operator_t op;
        function_t func;
        num_t num;
        bracket_t br;
    };
} token_t;
```

The entire project in its ongoing state can be found on its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/carefulnow1/sci-calc).

Comment: This is a better fit on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site since there doesn't seem to be a concrete problem here.

Comment: @tadman but I don't have any code that I'd like to be reviewed.

Comment: As it is, this is just way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TomasBy I want to verify whether a string given by the user is a valid infix string. E.g. 5+2 would be valid, and yield seven, whereas (5+2 would be invalid, as there are mismatched brackets. However there are also things such as missing operands and operators etc. I was wondering if there was a generic algorithm to do this, such as there is the Dijkstra's method for converting to RPN. See https://github.com/carefulnow1/sci-calc/blob/master/parse/infix_test_strings

Comment: @TomasBy ah okay, thank you for the help. Would you mind explaining as to why it's a bad idea to validate during the initial tokenisation?

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. Please do research on your own, best get a book (some introductory C books include the necessary functions). Come back if you have a **specific** question. Read [ask].

Comment: @tadman: Please be careful directing people to code review. They have specific requirements. Reasd their FAQ and their specific FAQ directed to SO migrators.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't suggest this was a tutoring site, and while I'm not sure how citing multiple books/lectures implies that I've done no research of my own, a C book would not be of great use here as it is less a C-specific question and more a question about algorithms.

Comment: I didn't say it is a _bad_ idea, but it is probably easier to do tokenisation first, as that is a clear and simple task.

Comment: 1) Your comments implied this. 2) Your question apparently asks for an implementation. Why else mention the language, showing some C code  and using the tag?

Comment: @Olaf 1) "At what point in the aformentioned process(es) should I validate the input string, and how can I go about that?" does not ask for an implementation. If my question sounded like it was doing so, I'm sorry, however I was simply asking which of the three options I provided was the best, and if there was any generally accepted algorithm for doing so. 2) I'm not saying the language is completely irrelevant, however the primary focus of the question is to do with an algorithm. 3) I'm not going to continue having this pointless argument.

Comment: All of them. When you see a problem, that means the string is not valid. If you don't see any problems then the string must be valid. If there are problems your code doesn't catch, make it catch them. Having separate validation and parsing steps *almost always* leads to bugs.